# Is there a generalization of the measure theoretic change-of-variables formula to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

In Bogachev's Measure Theory, he states the following:

Suppose we are given two spaces $X,Y$ with $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and an $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$-measurable mapping $f\colon X \to Y$. Then, for any bounded (or bounded from below) measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$, the formula
\begin{equation}
\mu \circ f^{-1} \colon B \mapsto \mu(f^{-1}(B)), \quad B \in \mathcal{B}.
\end{equation}

In connection with this, he states the following result.

**3.6.1 Theorem:** Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative measure. A $\mathcal{B}$-measurable function $g$ on $Y$ is integrable with respect to the measure $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ precisely when the function $g\circ f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$. In addtion, one has
\begin{equation}
\int_Y g(y) \mu\circ f^{-1}(dy) = \int_X g(f(x)) \mu(dx).
\end{equation}

He defines a measurable function as

**2.1.1 Definition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, i.e., a space with a $\sigma$-algebra. A function $g \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^1$ is called measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$ (or $\mathcal{A}$-measurable) if $\{x : g(x) < c\} \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}^1$.

Does the same (or a similar) result hold if $g \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^n$, for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$? If not, what if we impose some extra conditions on $g$, like continuity and boundedness?

Comment: For $Y=\Bbb R^n$ or any other space with measure and any measurable function $g\colon Y\to\Bbb R$ you can say that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is measurable if for every $c\in\Bbb R $ the set $\{x\in X\mid g(f(x))< c\}$ is measurable. This is a straightforward generalization. Do you need something else?

Comment: @markvs Thanks, let me think about it. Maybe it was not clear what $f$ is supposed to be. I added some more details before the theorem.

Comment: In the case of some other target  instead of $\Bbb R$ you need to define $<c$ in the definition. You can simply say that the preimage of every measurable set is measurable.

Comment: @markvs Sure, we can generalize measurability that way, but how do we know the theorem still holds?

Comment: Write $g$ in components as $g(x) = (g_1(x), \dots, g_n(x))$ and apply the $\mathbb{R}^1$ theorem to each of the $g_i$.  The definition of measurability of a function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will ensure that each $g_i$ is measurable.  (Or in some books that may even *be* the definition of measurability of a function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)